# Add numbers in c#

Tags: c#, numbers, addition

i have a numerical textbox which I need to add it's value to another number 
I have tried this code

```
String add = (mytextbox.Text + 2)
```

but it add the number two as another character like if the value of my text box is 13 the result will become 132

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String add = (Convert.ToInt32(mytextbox.Text) + 2).ToString();
```

You need to convert the text to an integer to do the calculation.

Answer (score 18):

The type of `mytextbox.Text` is *string*. You need to parse it as a number in order to perform integer arithmetic, e.g.

```
int parsed = int.Parse(mytextbox.Text);
int result = parsed + 2;
string add = result.ToString(); // If you really need to...
```

Note that you may wish to use [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) in order to handle the situation where the contents of the text box is *not* an integer, without having to catch an exception. For example:

```
int parsed;
if (int.TryParse(mytextbox.Text, out parsed))
{
    int result = parsed + 2;
    string add = result.ToString();
    // Use add here    
}
else
{
    // Indicate failure to the user; prompt them to enter an integer.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const int addend = 2; 
string myTextBoxText = mytextbox.Text;
var doubleArray = new double[myTextBoxText.ToCharArray().Length];
for (int index = 0; index < myTextBoxText.ToCharArray().Length; index++)
{
    doubleArray[index] = 
        Char.GetNumericValue(myTextBoxText.ToCharArray()[index]) 
        * (Math.Pow(10, (myTextBoxText.ToCharArray().Length - 1) - index));
}
string add  = 
    (doubleArray.Aggregate((term1, term2) => term1 + term2) + addend).ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int intValue = 0;
if(int.TryParse(mytextbox.Text, out intValue))
{
    String add = (intValue + 2).ToString();
}
```

I prefer TryPase, then you know the fallback is going to be zero (or whatever you have defined as the default for intValue)

Comment: If you're going to use `TryParse`, I think it would generally be better to actually use the return value. Also, the existing value of `intValue` *isn't* used as the default - it's an `out` parameter, which means the original value is ignored; it doesn't even have to be definitely assigned.

Answer (score 1):

```
string add=(int.Parse(mytextbox.Text) + 2).ToString()
```

if you want to make sure the conversion doesn't throw any exception

```
  int textValue = 0;
  int.TryParse(TextBox.text, out textValue);
  String add = (textValue + 2).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `int.Parse` method to parse the text content into an integer:

```
String add = (int.Parse(mytextbox.Text) + 2).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have posted the most common answers, but just to give you an alternative, you could use a property to retrieve the integer value of the TextBox.

This might be a good approach if you need to reuse the integer several times:

```
private int MyTextBoxInt
{
    get
    {
        return Int32.Parse(mytextbox.Text);
    }
}
```

And then you can use the property like this:

```
int result = this.MyTextBoxInt + 2;
```