# check for the bigger value in c#

Tags: c#, validation, numbers

boxes containing numbers and i want to check if the value of the first text box is bigger than the other like:

`if (textbox1.Text > textbox2.Text){// do stuff}`

so how can i make something like this.

Comment: You probably want to accept an answer

Comment: What was wrong with the answers here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323118/add-numbers-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parse the text in the textbox to an `int` first:

```
if (int.Parse(textbox1.Text) > int.Parse(textbox2.Text)){// do stuff}
```

But beware: This will throw an exception, if any of the texts entered can't be parsed to an `int`. The cleaner approach would be to use `TryParse` if you can't be sure that the entered text is always in the correct format:

```
int number1;
int number2;

if(int.TryParse(textbox1.Text, out number1)
   && int.TryParse(textbox2.Text, out number2)
   && number1 > number2)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
double value1=Double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
double value2=Double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
if (value1>value2)
 .......
```

Would this do your job or you need something more?

Comment: Bah... This is what I get for answering before refreshing.

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to convert the strings to numbers. Assuming we 're talking about integers and the range of an `int` suits you, you can do this with:

```
var value1 = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
var value2 = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);

if (value1 > value2) { ... }
```

However, this will leave you exposed to exceptions resulting from the conversion (e.g. if a text is not a number but a string). In this case, [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) allows you to detect this situation and respond accordingly.

```
int value1, value2;
if (!int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out value1)) {
    // textBox1 does not hold a number
}
else if (!int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out value2)) {
    // textBox2 does not hold a number
}
else {
    // OK, we have both numbers:
    if (value1 > value2) { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since everyone is assuming integers, I'll be the odd man out...

```
double value1, value2;

Double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out value1);
Double.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out value2);

if(value1 < value2 ){ ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( Convert.ToInt32( textbox1.Text) > Convert.ToInt32( textbox2.Text))

{// do stuff}
```

or

```
if (int.Parse(textbox1.Text) > int.Parse(textbox2.Text))

{// do stuff}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int value1 = int.Parse(textbox1.Text);
int value2 = int.Parse(textbox2.Text);

if (value1  > value2 )
{
   // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int text1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
int text2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
if(text1 < text2)
{
// do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering you are dealing with textbox (and so I suppose the text is inserted by the user) I would suggest using `int.TryParse` approach:

```
private bool Validate()
{
   int v1 = 0;
   int v2 = 0;
   if (!int.TryParse(tb1.Text, out v1) || int.TryParse(tb2.Text, out v2))
      return false;

   // Make the comparison
   return v1 > v2;
}
```

More concise version (but less clear, at least for me):

```
private bool Validate()
{
   int v1 = 0;
   int v2 = 0;
   return int.TryParse(tb1.Text, out v1) && 
          int.TryParse(tb2.Text, out v2) && 
          v1 > v2;
}
```

Comment: You should always pass-in the variables to the function

Comment: Well, assuming it is a global validation function the answer is no. If I have well understood he is going to validate some sort of form and maybe he want to check also other controls.

Answer (score 1):

Over complicated FTW?

```
if (CompareNumbers(textbox1.Text,textbox2.Text) > 0){// do stuff}

int CompareNumbers( string s1, string s2 )
{
    if ( s1 == s2 )
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if ( s1 == null )
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if ( s2 == null )
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if ( s1.Length != s2.Length )
    {
        return ( s1.Length - s2.Length );
    }
    for ( int index = 0; index < s1.Length; index++ )
    {
        int ch1, ch2, compare;

        ch1 = ( s1[index] - 0x30 );
        ch2 = ( s2[index] - 0x30 );
        compare = 0;
        if ( ch1 < 0 || ch1 > 9 )
        {
            compare = -1;
        }
        if ( ch2 < 0 || ch2 > 9 )
        {
            compare += 1;
        }
        if ( compare != 0 )
        {
            return compare;
        }
        if ( ch1 != ch2 )
        {
            return ( ch1 - ch2 );
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the CompareValidator class:

```
    <asp:CompareValidator 
ID="cmpAmount" 
runat="server" 
ControlToCompare='TextBox2'
ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
Type="Double"
Operator="GreaterThanEqual" />
```